# Wordpress plugin that pic title form post title and first 100 words of post for the post description automatically ?

Tags: wordpress

I have a site and want to know is there any plugin available that can add title form post title and description from the post first 100 words?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Can you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: I want to add title and description automatically such when i post some thing then post title add into page title(into title tag) and first 100 words of post words add into meta description, is it possible with plugin or manually?